# Parsing LDAP attributes from String in Java

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

Is there a way to parse attributes from a `String`? For example, if I have the following:

```
CN=Doe, John: Markets (LDN),OU=Users,DC=FOOCORP,DC=COM
```

and would like to get that into an `Attributes` or set of `Attribute`-s, is there a utility class one could use that does all the proper escaping, or should I just knock up some implementation of my own?

I have the following code:

```
    String cnBase = "CN=Doe\\, John: Markets (LDN),OU=Users,DC=FOOCORP,DC=COM";

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(cnBase, "=");

    Attributes attributes = new BasicAttributes();

    String attributeId = null;
    String attributeValue = null;
    String previousToken = null;

    while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String token = st.nextToken();

        if (previousToken == null && attributeId == null)
        {
            // Get the attribute's id
            attributeId = token;
            continue;
        }

        if (attributeId != null)
        {
            if (token.contains(","))
            {
                attributeValue = token.substring(0, token.lastIndexOf(","));
            }
            else
            {
                attributeValue = token;
            }
        }

        if (attributeId != null && attributeValue != null)
        {
            // Add a new Attribute to the attributes object
            Attribute attribute = new BasicAttribute(attributeId, attributeValue);
            attributes.put(attribute);

            System.out.println(attribute.toString());

            attributeId = token.substring(token.lastIndexOf(",") + 1, token.length());
            attributeValue = null;
        }

        previousToken = token;
    }
```

Which I think can be re-written in a smarter way.

Comment: That's a DN, not an attribute.

Comment: Okay, is there a class in the standard JDK API that holds this and a respective class that can parse it from a `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNDI has a class called `LdapName` (misnamed), which represents a **distinguished name**. It's based on an obsolete RFC but it might be satisfactory.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: The links doesn't work anymore. @Terry Gardner do you still know a good source as an answer?